# How can I use my SanDisk Connect Wireless Flash Drive with my 12" MacBook

Tags: macos, wifi, usb, external-disk

I can access the drive on my iPhone, iPad and Android.

I am having trouble figuring out how to get it to work with my Mac

I am using Yosemite and I've done the latest firmware update on the drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [SanDisk Getting Started Guide](http://Wireless%20Stick%20Getting%20Started%20Guide), There are two steps to get your Mac connected:

1. Connect to the SanDisk WiFi Network.
2. Browse to http://www.sandisk.com/myconnect

---

Directly from the [Getting Started Guide](http://Wireless%20Stick%20Getting%20Started%20Guide):

[image]

These instructions work with PC or Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `172.25.63.1`
while connected to sandisk connect wireless drive, you may not be able to browse stuff but you could download your data and view them on your mac.

Answer (score -1):

Connect to Sandisk flash drive wifi signal. Go to http://www.sandisk.com/myconnect.

Comment: Links rot. Please add the relevant information behind that link to your answer.